# Custom Jackson module not used in Spring REST docs test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restdocs

I have written a small test on Spring REST docs with custom Jackson module (using Spring Boot 1.3). In my application main class, I only have `@SpringBootApplication`. I then have another class `JacksonCustomizations` that looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonCustomizations {

@Bean
public Module myCustomModule() {
    return new MyCustomModule();
}

static class MyCustomModule extends SimpleModule {
    public MyCustomModule() {

        addSerializer(ImmutableEntityId.class, new JsonSerializer<ImmutableEntityId>() {
            @Override
            public void serialize(ImmutableEntityId immutableEntityId, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
                jsonGenerator.writeNumber( (Long)immutableEntityId.getId() );
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

This customization is picked up perfectly. When I run the Spring Boot application, I see the JSON as it should be.

However, in my documentation test, the customization is not applied. This is the code of my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NoteControllerDocumentation {

@Rule
public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                             .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                             .build();

}


@Test
public void notesListExample() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/notes/"))
           .andExpect(status().isOk())
           .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
           .andDo(document("notes-list-example", responseFields(
                   fieldWithPath("[]").description("An array of <<note-example,note>>s."))));
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Import(JacksonCustomizations.class)
public static class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public NoteController noteController() {
        return new NoteController();
    }
}
```

}

Note how the application context in my test imports the `JacksonCustomizations` configuration.

Other things I found:

- Adding `@EnableWebMvc` on my boot application stops the customization from working.
- Removing the `@EnableWebMvc` on my test stops JSON being produced.

Comment: Did you try adding @Import(JacksonCustomizations.class) to NoteControllerDocumentation class ?

Comment: @reos does not make a difference

Comment: It sounds like Spring Boot hasn't auto-configured the `ObjectMapper` with your custom `Module`. That matches the fact that you haven't provided `SpringApplicationConfiguration` with the class(es) for your application so Spring Boot doesn't know what to do. In fact, the code that you've shared fails with an `IllegalStateException` that says "No configuration classes or locations found in @SpringApplicationConfiguration" because of this. Can you share a small sample project that contains the exact code that you're running to trigger the problem?

Comment: Doesn't `ContextConfiguration` uses the inner class `Configuration` automatically? Please download the sample project from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6373261/so-34156932.zip which shows the problem.

Comment: Aah, it wasn't clear (the formatting's a bit off) that `TestConfiguration` was an inner class. Thanks for the sample project. I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoteControllerDocumentation` isn't configured to use Spring Boot to create the application context. This means that Spring Boot's auto-configuration doesn't run and, therefore, your custom Jackson module isn't applied to the `ObjectMapper`.

The simplest solution to your problem is to delete your `TestConfiguration` class and update `SpringApplicationConfiguration` to reference `DemoApplication` instead. That'll leave you with the following code:

```
package com.example.controller;

import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.responseFields;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.example.DemoApplication;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NoteControllerDocumentation {

    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                                 .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                                 .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void notesListExample() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/notes/"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
               .andExpect(content().json("[{\"id\":1}]"))
               .andDo(print())
               .andDo(document("nodes-list-example", responseFields(
                       fieldWithPath("[]").description("An array of <<note-example,note>>s."))));
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you want more control over how your control is created (to inject a mock service, for example), you can use a custom configuration class. The key is to annotate that class with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so that Spring Boot's auto-configuration is enabled and the customization of the `ObjectMapper` is performed. This approach will leave you with the following code:

```
package com.example.controller;

import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.document;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.fieldWithPath;
import static org.springframework.restdocs.payload.PayloadDocumentation.responseFields;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import com.example.JacksonCustomizations;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class NoteControllerDocumentation {

    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                                 .apply(documentationConfiguration(restDocumentation))
                                 .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void notesListExample() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/notes/"))
               .andExpect(status().isOk())
               .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
               .andExpect(content().json("[{\"id\":1}]"))
               .andDo(print())
               .andDo(document("nodes-list-example", responseFields(
                       fieldWithPath("[]").description("An array of <<note-example,note>>s."))));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @Import(JacksonCustomizations.class)
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public NoteController notesController() {
            return new NoteController();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But what if my controller uses an autowired service or repository? How can I setup a mock for it? Referencing `DemoApplication` would inject the real services/repos.

Comment: You didn't mention that requirement in the question so I didn't address it. I've updated my answer with details of another approach.